# No class subtraction operator overloaded but still works

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Number {
    T1 value;
public:
    Number(const T1& val): value(val){};
    operator T2() { return (T2)(value / 2); }
    T1 operator+(const T1& val) { return value + val; }
};

int main() {
    Number<int, float>n1(10);
    Number<float, int>n2(3.0);
    cout << n1 + n2 << ", " << n2 + n1 << ", " << n1 - n2 << endl;
}
```

In spite having no subtraction operator overloaded this code still works and outputs:
`11, 8, 4`.

Shouldn't it throw an error at compile time ?

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: try to see what happens when you make the `operator T2()` explicit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the compiler sees `n1 - n2`, it performs an overload resolution. For any pair of promoted arithmetic types `L` and `R`, the following signatures participate in overload resolution:

```
LR operator-(L, R)
```

where `LR` is the result of usual arithmetic conversions on `L` and `R`. (See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Additive_operators)) No other signature that participates in overload resolution is relevant.

Therefore, `n1` is converted to `5.0f` with the help of `operator T2()`, and `n2` is similarly converted to `1`. And `5.0f - 1` is `4.0f`.

Answer (score 0):

`n2` has conversion to `int` defined, `n1` has conversion to `float` defined, `int` can be automatically promoted to float. I would expect the expression `n1-n2` to be of type `float`.

Note that the compiler wouldn't perform more than one *user-defined* conversion on an argument.